# Creating custom gesture in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, gesture

I need to implement creating custom gesture(like **Gesture Builder** in **Android**) in my iPhone application. So, is there any good tutorial or sample application?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is to watch the WWDC sessions on gestures.  They're free and available through iTunes if you're a registered developer.